# Split the string based on different criteria [Optimization Required]

Tags: java, java-8

I have one input string and If the string contains elseif, then I need to split that string to multiple lines as showed in expected output.

```
if ((tag eq 200)) then
    set weight 200
elseif ((tag eq 300)) then
    set weight 300
elseif ((tag eq 400)) then
    set weight 400
elseif ((tag eq 250)) then
    set weight 0
else pass endif
```

I've implemented below code to split as I showed above. It is giving an expected result. But the below code is not optimized one. Can someone suggest any optimization for the below piece of code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "if ((tag eq 200)) then set weight 200  elseif ((tag eq 300)) then set weight 300  elseif ((tag eq 400)) then set weight 400 elseif ((tag eq 250)) then set weight 0 else pass endif";
        System.out.println(str);

        if(str.contains("elseif")) {
            int lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf("then");
            String subString = str.substring(0, lastIndex + 4);
            splitTextByThen(subString);
            String subString1 = str.substring(lastIndex+4 , str.length());
            splitTextByElseIfOrElse(subString1);
        }
    }

    public static void splitTextByThen(String input) {
        String[] arr = input.split("then");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            splitTextByElseIfOrElse(arr[i] + "then");
        }
    }

    public static void splitTextByElseIfOrElse(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        if(input.contains("elseif")) {
            String[] arr = input.split("elseif");
            al.add(arr[0]);
            al.add("elseif " +arr[1]);
        }else if (input.contains("else")) {
            String[] arr = input.split("else");
            al.add(arr[0]);
            al.add("else " +arr[1]);
        }
        else {
            al.add(input);
        }

        for (String string : al) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By chance, you are implementing a text parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code can look much simpler (and more readable) if you use regular expressions:

```
String result = str.replaceAll(" (?=elseif|else)", "\n")
                   .replaceAll("(?<=then) ", "\n    ");
```

This uses lookahead to match a space followed by `elseif` or `else`, replacing with `\n`, and lookbehind to match a space following `then` and replacing it with `\n` followed by 4 spaces.

And the output of that is:

```
if ((tag eq 200)) then
    set weight 200 
elseif ((tag eq 300)) then
    set weight 300 
elseif ((tag eq 400)) then
    set weight 400
elseif ((tag eq 250)) then
    set weight 0
else pass endif
```